# populate dropdown menu using bootstrap in grails

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I want to create menu in grails view using bootstrap. Menu are creating but on click it is not showing the dropdown list. Here are dropdown under Messages and Admin link. I am using grails 2.4.2 version. I have the bootstrap folder under my web-app. Can anyone please help me on this please ? Here are my code below :

my view files >>>

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap 3</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <head>

    <g:javascript plugin="jquery" library="jquery" src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'bootstrap/css', file: 'bootstrap.min.css')}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'bootstrap/css', file: 'bootstrap-responsive.css')}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'bootstrap/css', file: 'bootstrap.css')}" type="text/css">

    <script type="javascript" src="${resource(dir: 'bootstrap/js', file: 'bootstrap.js')}"></script>

    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
    <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>

</head>

<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown pull-right">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Admin <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done. I didn't know that I will have to paste the bootstrap.js file under grails-app/assets/javascripts folder. When I have paste it there, it works fine. thank you.

Comment: it's hard to guess, but it seems that you are mixing resource and asset plugin syntax (assumption: putting files in the asset folder but using the resource() functions)